# Why am I having KeyError: 'val_acc'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In my Keras code, I did the following:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(border_irregularity_features,y, epochs=5, batch_size=1, validation_split=0.33)
...
...
accuracy = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
```

However, I'm having the following error:

```
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
KeyError: 'val_acc'
```

Why is that? What am I missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT-1**

When I did:

```
print history.history.keys()
```

I got:

```
['acc', 'loss', 'val_acc', 'val_loss']
```

Comment: `history.history` has no key named "`val_acc`". You can safely try to `get` the key with `history.history.get('val_acc', None)` where `None` is the default value if the key is missing. You may want to `print` all the keys if you need to know the names before trying to get a specific key: `print(history.history.keys())`, assuming `history.history` is an instance of `dict`

Comment: cannot reproduce your error with MNIST data; can you pls post the results of `history.history`, as well as your Keras version?

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies. Please see **EDIT-1**

Comment: Are you sure the source of error is on the following line?
`val_acc = history.history['val_acc']`
Do you get the same error if you change it to:
`val_acc = history.history['val_loss']`
?

Answer (score 7):

From tensorflow 2 the history keys are as follows : (['val_loss', 'val_accuracy', 'val_precision', 'val_recall', 'loss', 'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall'])

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no issue with the code per-se. I have copied part of the code from another script I had. I just erased the underscores in "val_acc" and "val_loss" and typed them again, and it worked!

Maybe some special characters where embedded when copying and pasting?